# Angular using ngModel in isolation set error

Tags: angular, angular-ngmodel

I'm using `ngModel` without a form in isolation.  Its something like the following

```html
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="cusName" #cusName="ngModel" (change)="validate(cusName)" />
```

In the `.ts` file I do some backend validation on the `change` event.  If there is an error I want to set the error in the `cusName` ngModel passed into the `validate` method.  I tried to do `custName.errors = {}` in the `.ts` file,  but then I get an error saying cannot set value.  My ideal scenario is that I want to set the `valid` property of the `cusName` ngModel to false and set a custom error on it as well through the `errors` property.  I can of course introduce additional variables into the model and extend it, but I prefer not to do that.

Comment: Have you included `@ViewChild` for your form?

Comment: I don't see the relevance of `@ViewChild` here, and I'm not using a form in the first place.

Comment: You need to have form directive because `ngModel` searches its controller in order to register itself and leverage validation capabilities.

Comment: this is not always true, I have seen many examples using ngModel in isolation without using a form.  You can also add custom error validators as well.  The problem here is that I'm not sure how to set it in the `.ts` file.

Comment: As far as I know `ngModel` directive searches for `ngForm` directive in the DOM tree. When it find one it registers itself with it. Something like `ngFormController.addControl(...)` so then you can set your error.

Comment: If you wish do some custom validation, I'd tell you look into reactive forms rather than template driven forms. It offers a more intuitive way to set custom validations on the input.